# Using a Blob to get a file from database

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, blob

I'm working on a database project using Oracle Express Edition and using JDBC. I have an excel spreadsheet within the database that I am working with (editing, updating, etc.) I recently started reading about BLOBS, so I just have a general idea about what it is, but I would like to know if it's possible to use the BLOB library in my project in order to download the updated spreadsheet and save it to my computer. I need the updated files saved, and I would prefer if I did it by code. Is this possible, by importing the BLOB class into my project, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Okay, and you have some code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your question relates to [this class](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/BLOB.html).

It is important to note that a `BLOB` is a "Binary Large OBject", and it's a database term used to describe storing arbitrary serialized data into a database. The Java class here allows you to more easily access and modify such an object in a database. It is not referring to the database itself - or the similar spreadsheet you're using.

Your general question (while very broad and likely to get closed) is easily answered; yes. But you'd have to implement several parts:

- Download the spreadsheet
- Import updates into your database

The class you cite is useful for the latter, but perhaps not the former.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Nathaniel. I was researching about BLOBS and understood what it was in general, but I couldn't find anything that answered my specific question, which is why I chose to ask here on stackoverflow. My question was marked as "off-topic" and I understand why, but I appreciate your response, which is what I was looking for.